# Is it ok to extend Python module like this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, composition, python-module

I have a base Python module `basemodule.py` with many functions and classes. Now I want to create many new modules, `new1.py`, `new2.py`, `new3.py`, etc.

Each of these modules will only add or change 1-2 functions in the base module. I am looking for a way to extend the base module, so that I don't need to repeat many codes.

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705964/how-do-i-extend-a-python-module-python-twitter/2706023#2706023), Rizwan has suggested a very interesting way to do this.

*extmodule.py*:

```
from basemodule import *
import basemodule

#code is in extended module
def makeBalls(a,b):
    foo = makeBall(a)
    bar = makeBall(b)
    print foo,bar

#function from extended module overwrites base module
def override():
    print "OVERRIDE TWO"

#function from extended module calls base module first
def dontoverride():
    basemodule.dontoverride()
    print "THIS WAS PRESERVED"
```

In this example, the base module has been imported twice, using `import ..` and `from .. import ..`.

Is it ok to extend Python module like this? Will it cause any undefined behaviour?

Comment: This is what OOP is for. Use it.

Comment: this will certainly _work_, but it's likely to confuse anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While maybe not so common this is certainly a valid method of [code reuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) in Python and has it's uses, e.g. substituting real modules with mocked ones for testing or rolling a plugin system.

It's a form of [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) on the module level, which may be more flexible than the usual [object inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)), see [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Though you should take care not to lose code clarity by using this approach in some obscure ways. I'd say this is usually expected to be done on class level.