# Want to add function to a module

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add with a function `log100()` to the math module:

```
def log100(number):
  ans = math.log(number,100)
  return ans
```

I can't see how I can do it without using "os" module to add directories.

Comment: Just fyi: [you don't need to add your question's topic to the title.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/174780)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extend a python module? Adding new functionality to the \`python-twitter\` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705964/how-do-i-extend-a-python-module-adding-new-functionality-to-the-python-twitter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it isn't the best idea -- you risk confusing people who read your code later by messing with standard modules -- you could do something like

```
math.log100 = lambda x: math.log(x, 100)
```

or

```
def log100(x):
    return math.log(x, 100)

math.log100 = log100
```

, which then can be called as

```
math.log100(10) # Output 0.5
```